# Create dynamic Ninject instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ninject

I'm trying to create an instance of a class dynamically using Ninject,
I got to a point that I have a Type variable that has the correct Interface and I'm trying to get the class I need. 
it seems like I'm passing a wrong value to the kernel get function.

```
Type instanceType = GetTypeFromAntherDll();

Kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyModule());

var instance = Kernel.Get<BaseHandler>(instanceType);
```

this code has a compilation problem the error is

```
cannot convert from 'system.Type' to 'Ninject.Parameters.IParamter'
```

- I have a module with all of the binding definitions

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-generic `Get` method that gets the type as a parameter -

```
Type instanceType = GetTypeFromAntherDll();
Kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyModule());
BaseHandler instance = (BaseHandler)Kernel.Get(instanceType); // <-- This method
```

Comment: That works but now I'm getting a different error 
' No matching bindings are available'
but there is a matching binding in the module

Comment: var instance = (BaseHandler)Kernel.Get(Type.GetType(instanceType.AssemblyQualifiedName));

thats works for me